# Making custom User that extends V and OUser

Tags: orientdb

I need to create a User class that allows for both record-level security as well as vertex properties, but `OUser` already extends `OIdentity`.

I'm also wondering if there's a way to get rid of the automatically generated `admin` user, as it seems redundant that I can connect to my database using the `root` user defined in the `orientdb-server-config.xml`, and I don't need that user (at least right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let OIdentity to extend V:

```
alter class OIdentity superclass V
```

So now OUser and ORole are Vertices.

About "admin" you could also drop it if you always use the server's root user (That is God)