# OUser inheriting from ORestricted in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

In a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689821/making-custom-user-that-extends-v-and-ouser?answertab=active#tab-top) I read that to extend `OUser` from `V` the best solution is to:

```
alter class OIdentity superclass V
```

At the same time I would like all `V` and `E` to extend from `ORestricted` as mentioned [in this documentation](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Security#record-level-security)

```
alter class V superclass ORestricted
alter class E superclass ORestricted
```

If I would implement both solutions I would end up having the classes `OUser` and `ORole` inheriting from `ORestricted`.

Is this correct? Or it could create any sort of issue?

Comment: Did you finally succeeded with this approach ?